# Sort by aggregate value in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, aggregate

Let's say I have the following student data:

```
classroom     gender  student_id
-------------------------------------
First Grade   M       123
First Grade   F       124
First Grade   F       125
Second Grade  M       126
Third Grade   M       127
...
```

I want to produce the following result: top 3 biggest classrooms ordered by total number of students with detail for each:

```
classroom          boys_count  girls_count  total_count
--------------------------------------------------
Third Grade        30          30           60
First Grade        20          5            25
Fourth Grade       10          10           20
```

How can I do that in sql ? If necessary, I can use specific postrges features.

---

What I tried so far:

```
SELECT count(*) as total_count
  , gender
  , classroom
ORDER BY 1
GROUP BY classroom, gender
LIMIT 3
```

Then I re-organise results in some scripting language. But this is too slow. I want to have the correct results with one query

Comment: This is a very basic SQL query.  Do you know the language?

Comment: That is no aggregation. This is simple addition and ordering by that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff True. I realise that I oversimplified my real problem. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select classroom as name,
       sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as boys_count,
       sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as girls_count,
       count(*) as total_count
from your_table
group by classroom
order by count(*) desc
limit 3
```

Comment: There are three alternatives BTW: `count(*) filter (where gender = 'M') as boys_count`, `count(nullif(gender,'F')) as boys_count` and `sum((gender='M')::int) as boys_count` Depending what is more readable for you.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. (Dunno why, I was trying to `group by gender`. Just grouping by classroom is the way to go)